# Laravel 4 force SSL without losing paremeters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i am using laravel filter to redirect incoming `http` to `https`

```
            // SSL
            Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
            {
                if( ! Request::secure())
                {
                    return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
                }

            });
```

and in controller

```
        $this->beforeFilter('force.ssl');
```

The problem is when an incomming `http` is like this
`http://myweb.com?cod=123&page=2` it redirects to `https://myweb.com/` and lose the parameters `?cod=123&page=2` how can i force SSL and keep the parameters?
Thanks.

I am using laravel 4

Comment: which laravel version?

Comment: I am using Laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to it is this.

Add this to your filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //
    if( ! Request::secure() )
    {
        return Redirect::secure( Request::path() );
    }
});
```

That would make every request https.

Answer (score 0):

I was using something similar to @osleonard but it drops the GET parameters in the URL so I came up with this snippit.

Place this in your filters.php file and everywhere will be forced to https while retaining URL parameters:

```
//force ssl
App::before(function () {
if(!Request::secure() && App::environment() != 'local')
{
    $baseHost = Request::getHttpHost();
    $requestUri = Request::getRequestUri();
    $newLink = 'https://'.$baseHost.$requestUri;

    return Redirect::to($newLink);
}});
```